# Use of tf.while_loop with 1-D tensors as input to produce 2-D tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to perform a loop in parallel wit GPUs of a function that computes independently the rows of a matrix. I was using `map_fn`, but to be able to have the parallel computing enabled with the eager execution, as far as I understand, I've to use the `while_loop` function.
Unfortunately I find not very intuitive how to use this function, so I'm kindly asking to you how to convert `map_fn` to `while_loop` in my code. Here a simplified version of the code:

```
*some 1-D float tensors*

def compute_row(ithStep):
    *operations on the 1-D tensors that return a 1-D tensor with fixed length*
    return values

image = tf.map_fn(compute_row, tf.range(0,nRows))
```

The version with `while_loop` I wrote, following the example in the documentation and other questions here on Stackoverflow is:

```
*some 1-D float tensors*

def compute_row(i):
    *operations on the 1-D tensors that return a 1-D tensor with fixed length*
    return values

def condition(i):
    return tf.less(i, nRows)

i = tf.constant(0)

image = tf.while_loop(condition, compute_row, [i])
```

But in this case what I obtain is:

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=list str=[TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)]

Second structure: type=list ... *a long list of tensors*
```

Where is the mistake? Thanks in advance. If needed I can provide a simplified runnable code.

EDIT: adding below the runnable code

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot

#Defining the data which normally are loaded from file:
#1- matrix of x position-time values, with weights, in sparse format
matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size = 100).astype(float).reshape(10,10)
x = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[0]
times = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[1]
weights = numpy.random.rand(x.size)

#2- array of y positions
nStepsY = 5
y = numpy.arange(1,nStepsY+1)

#3- the size of the final matrix
nRows = nStepsY
nColumns = 80

# Building the TF tensors
x = tf.constant(x, dtype = tf.float32)
times = tf.constant(times, dtype = tf.float32)
weights = tf.constant(weights, dtype = tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(y, dtype = tf.float32)

# the function to iterate
def compute_row(i):
    yTimed = tf.multiply(y[i],times)
    positions = tf.round((x-yTimed)+50)
    positions = tf.cast(positions, dtype=tf.int32)
    values = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(weights, positions, nColumns)
    return values

image = tf.map_fn(compute_row, tf.range(0,nRows), dtype=tf.float32)

%matplotlib inline
pyplot.imshow(image, aspect = 10)
pyplot.colorbar(shrink = 0.75,aspect = 10)
```

The output image is:
[image: output of the example code]

Comment: Please, provide your simplified code.

Comment: @Lescurel thanks for the answer, I've just added the example code with the output with the map_fn version. Please tell me if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

To construct a while loop, you need to define two functions:

- the conditional function: when this function returns false, the loop stops
- the loop body function, that performs the wanted operations. In your case, because you want to build a Tensor, you can see that as an accumulation function: the function takes the Tensor as an argument, and append a new row at the end.

Knowing that, we can define the two functions:

First, the loop body. Let's reuse `compute_row` function to compute the value of the new row based on the value of `i`, and append the new row to our accumulator using `tf.concat`. We make sure that the shapes are compatible for he concatenation by adding one dimension to the new row. We also increase the value of the counter `i` by 1.

```
def loop_body(i, accumulator):
    new_row = compute_row(i)
    accumulator = tf.concat([accumulator, new_row[tf.newaxis,:]],axis=0)
    return i+1, accumulator
```

Next the condition: in that case, we just need to check that the value of `i` is not greater than the number of rows wanted.

```
def cond(i,accumulator):
    return tf.less(i,nRows)
```

Note that the two functions, `loop_body` and `cond` must have the same signature. (That explains why `cond` takes a second unused argument).

Now, we can put that together in the `while_loop` call:

```
i0 = tf.constant(0) # we initialize the counter i at 0
# we initialize the accumulator with an empty Tensor of dimension 1 equal to 0. 
accumulator = tf.zeros((0, nColumns)) 
final_i, image = tf.while_loop(cond, loop_body, loop_vars=[i0, accumulator])
```

to make sure that it reproduces the same values as the `map_fn` version, we can compare the two results:

```
>>> image_map = tf.map_fn(compute_row_map, tf.range(0, nRows), dtype=tf.float32)
>>> tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(image, image_map))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```

Comment: Hello Lescurel, thank you so much for your answer and sorry for the delay. Finally I had some time to test the while_loop function as you suggested, and it works perfectly, producing the same output. Unfortunately I noticed a significant increase in computation time with respect to the older code with TensorFlow 1.13 map_fn, with the same device, input and output, from ~9.2 s to ~33.2 s. TensorFlow 2 with map_fn in eager execution runs with the same time. Is it in your opinion something related to this question, or should I accept your answer and open a new one?